# Bind WPF DataGrid Column Header Text in a Cell Values

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I'm having a DataGrid, I wish to append the Column Header Text in each value in a Cell

The XAML Source Code is

```
<Window x:Class="DataGrid_Index.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:cust="clr-namespace:DataGrid_Index" >
    <Grid>

        <DataGrid Name="Grid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding MobileList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionUnit="Cell" SelectionChanged="Grid1_SelectionChanged" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <!--Column 1-->
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MobileName}" Header="Name" />
                <!--Column 2-->
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MobileOS}" Header="OS" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The C# View Model is

```
public class MobileVM : ViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Mobile> _mobileList = new ObservableCollection<Mobile>();
    public ObservableCollection<Mobile> MobileList
    {
        get { return _mobileList; }
        set { _mobileList = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public MobileVM()
    {
        MobileList = new ObservableCollection<Mobile>()
        {
            new Mobile() { MobileName = "iPhone 6", MobileOS = "IOS" },
            new Mobile() { MobileName = "Galaxy S6", MobileOS = "Android" },
            new Mobile() { MobileName = "Lumina", MobileOS = "Windows" }
        };
    }
}

public class Mobile
{
    public string MobileName { get; set; }
    public string MobileOS { get; set; }
}
```

I'm expecting output

```
        Name                  OS
_________________________________________
    Name: iPhone 6        OS: IOS
    Name: Galaxy S6       OS: Android
    Name: Lumina          OS: Windows
```

How to bind the `Column.Header` in a Cell ? Kindly assist me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with a MultiBinding like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" x:Name="NameC">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0}: {1}">
                                <Binding ElementName="NameC" Path="Header"></Binding>
                                <Binding Path="MobileName"></Binding>

                            </MultiBinding>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
```

The `StringFormat` allows you to some more customization.

Hope this helps